# In python, what's the proper way to implement a class whose constructor could fail?

Tags: python

For example, in the constructor I need to grab some resources which could fail, in that case the class shouldn't be instantiated.

Should I throw exception in the constructor?

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.rsc = get_resource():
        assert self.rsc
```

And try to catch it in the instantiation code?

```
try:
    a = Foo()
except:
    a = None
```

Then later code checks if a is None.

Comment: Better to just add `rsc` as a constructor parameter that gets passed in. As a result you get two benefits: a lighter-weight constructor, and one that can't fail. Then if you want, you can provide a function that gets the resource implicitly, and either returns None or calls the constructor with the resource.

Comment: What you proposed sounds fine.  The question is what you want to happen if that failure occurs.  If it's the calling code that needs to handle it, then you should catch the exception in the calling code as you suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding my earlier comment into an answer:

It's better to add the resource as a constructor parameter, like this:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, rsc):
        self.rsc = rsc
```

This approach has a number of benefits:

- The constructor can no longer fail
- You no longer have an expensive constructor
- You have looser coupling between Foo and its resource type

And if you like the interface of implicitly acquiring a resource, it is easy to wrap this. A simple function like `make_foo` attempts to acquire the resource automatically, returning None (or raising an error, if you prefer) when it cannot:

```
def make_foo():
    rsc = get_resource()
    if rsc:
        return Foo(rsc)
    else:
        return None
```

Answer (score -3):

Not really a problem, just add `try...except` in the `init` function and have it assign a specific value like `None` in case of failure, or add additional features

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        try:
            self.rsc = get_resource()
            self.success = True
        except:
            self.rsc = None
            self.success = False

a = Foo()
if a.success:
    print(a.rsc)
else:
    do_something_else()
```

Comment: I downvoted because this interface makes it very easy to work with the object incorrectly, by forgetting to check whether it was successfully created. Also, it is syntactically invalid, with an trailing extra `:`.

Comment: removed the `:` so tnx, but I don't see a way around your problem of forgetting to check, you could very well forget to check if `get_resource` itself failed even outside of a class

Comment: Your version forces every user of this class to check for success. Compare to, for example, my version, which checks it only once, in a single function that can be reused many times.

Comment: I agree that having the check is a less robust way to clarify the success of the creation then either passing the resource itself or raising an exception